# Log4j filerotation doesn't work in spark-yarn

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn

I submit my application to yarn with a custom log4j property. The custom config itself is recognized and used by both the driver and executor except the log rotation part.
(The log rotation itself works well without yarn)

```
Hadoop: 2.7.0
Spark : 3.1.1
OS: Windows10
```

**spark-submit:**

```
./bin/spark-submit.cmd --class scala_spark.ScalaApp --master yarn --files "./myapp/log4j-test.properties" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-test.properties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-test.properties" --deploy-mode cluster ./myapp/myApp.jar
```

**log4j-test.properties:**

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1, my_file

log4j.logger.scala_spark=DEBUG

 # A1 Appender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender       
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# file Appender
log4j.appender.my_file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.my_file.append=true
log4j.appender.my_file.file=./myApp.log
log4j.appender.my_file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.my_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.my_file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

**Result:**
In `$HADOOP_HOME\logs\userlogs\application_1617490627891_0001\container_1617490627891_0001_01_000001`   only stderr and stdout can be found but not the myApp.log

**NOTE:** 
I am 100% sure that log4j-test.properties is in effect because when I change something like rootlogger to TRACE, then those extra TRACE,DEBUG logs will appear in stdout.
If I change to log4j.rootLogger=INFO, my_file , then nothing will printed to stdout ofcz, but myApp.log still nowhere.

**EDIT:**
I thought maybe the app can't create the file for some reason ( like permission issue), but there are no errors at all in the app,spark,yarn,hdfs logs.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
I had the change the log file location to :

```
log4j.appender.file_appender.file=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/myApp.log
```

> If you need a reference to the proper location to put log files in the
> YARN so that YARN can properly display and aggregate them, use
> spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir in your log4j.properties

source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html