# Dataproc: limit log size for long-running / streaming Spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I've a Spark Structured Streaming job on GCP Dataproc - which picks up data from Kafka, does processing and pushes data back into kafka topics.

Couple of questions :

1. Does Spark put all the log (incl. INFO, WARN etc) into stderr ?
   What I notice is that stdout is empty, while all the logging is put in to stderr
2. Is there a way for me to expire the data in stderr (i.e. expire the older logs) ?
   Since I've a long running streaming job, the stderr gets filled up over time and nodes/VMs become unavailable.

Pls advice.

Here is output of the yarn logs command :

```
root@versa-structured-stream-v1-w-1:/home/karanalang# yarn logs -applicationId application_1663623368960_0008 -log_files stderr -size -500
2022-09-19 23:25:34,876 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at versa-structured-stream-v1-m/10.142.0.62:8032
2022-09-19 23:25:35,144 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at versa-structured-stream-v1-m/10.142.0.62:10200
Can not find any log file matching the pattern: [stderr] for the container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000003 within the application: application_1663623368960_0008
Container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000002 on versa-structured-stream-v1-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
=======================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 19 23:25:35 +0000 2022
LogLength:43251469683
LogContents:
 applianceName=usa-isn0784-rt01, tenantName=NOV, mstatsTimeBlock=1663507200, tenantId=2, vsnId=0, mstatsTotSentOctets=11596, mstatsTotRecvdOctets=24481, mstatsTotSessDuration=300000, mstatsTotSessCount=1, mstatsType=sdwan-acc-ckt-app-stats, appId=https, site=usa-isn0784-rt01, accCkt=WAN-DIA, siteId=442, accCktId=1, user=10.126.117.196, risk=3, productivity=3, family=general-internet, subFamily=web, bzTag=Unknown,topic=syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3,customer=versa  type(row) is ->  <class 'str'>
End of LogType:stderr.This log file belongs to a running container (container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000002) and so may not be complete.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000001 on versa-structured-stream-v1-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
=======================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 19 22:54:55 +0000 2022
LogLength:17367929
LogContents:
on syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3-2
22/09/19 22:52:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-0f984ad9-f663-4ce1-9ef1-349419f3e6ec-1714963016-executor-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0f984ad9-f663-4ce1-9ef1-349419f3e6ec-1714963016-executor] Resetting offset for partition syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3-2 to offset 449568676.
22/09/19 22:54:55 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************


root@versa-structured-stream-v1-w-1:/home/karanalang# yarn logs -applicationId application_1663623368960_0008 -log_files stderr -size -500
2022-09-19 23:26:01,439 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at versa-structured-stream-v1-m/10.142.0.62:8032
2022-09-19 23:26:01,696 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at versa-structured-stream-v1-m/10.142.0.62:10200
Can not find any log file matching the pattern: [stderr] for the container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000003 within the application: application_1663623368960_0008
Container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000002 on versa-structured-stream-v1-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
=======================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 19 23:26:02 +0000 2022
LogLength:44309782124
LogContents:
, tenantId=3, vsnId=0, mstatsTotSentOctets=48210, mstatsTotRecvdOctets=242351, mstatsTotSessDuration=300000, mstatsTotSessCount=34, mstatsType=dest-stats, destIp=165.225.216.24, mstatsAttribs=,topic=syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3,customer=versa  type(row) is ->  <class 'str'>
22/09/19 23:26:02 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
End of LogType:stderr.This log file belongs to a running container (container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000002) and so may not be complete.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_e01_1663623368960_0008_01_000001 on versa-structured-stream-v1-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
=======================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 19 22:54:55 +0000 2022
LogLength:17367929
LogContents:
on syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3-2
22/09/19 22:52:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-0f984ad9-f663-4ce1-9ef1-349419f3e6ec-1714963016-executor-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-0f984ad9-f663-4ce1-9ef1-349419f3e6ec-1714963016-executor] Resetting offset for partition syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3-2 to offset 449568676.
22/09/19 22:54:55 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
End of LogType:stderr.
```

Update :
Based on @Dagang's note, i'm using the RollingFileAppender in the log4j.properties .. and the new log file is getting created. However - some data is still getting into std err.

Here is the updated code :

```
spark-submit

gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark process-appstat.py \
  --cluster $CLUSTER  \
  --properties ^#^spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2#spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true#spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=120s#spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true#spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-executor.properties#spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-driver.properties\
  --jars=gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/isolation-forest_2.4.3_2.12-2.0.8.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.2.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/bson-4.0.5.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar \
  --files=gs://kafka-certs/versa-kafka-gke-ca.p12,gs://kafka-certs/syslog-vani-noacl.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarm-compression-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarm-compression-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstats-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstats-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/insights-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/insights-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/intfutil-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/intfutil-user-test.p12,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/metrics.properties,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/params.cfg,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-anomaly-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-anomaly-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-agg-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-agg-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarmblock-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarmblock-user-test.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-alarmblock-test-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-bandwidth-test-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-appstat-test-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-alarmblock-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-bandwidth-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/versa-appstat-user.p12,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/log4j-executor.properties,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/log4j-driver.properties  \
  --region $REGION \
  --py-files streams.zip,utils.zip \
  -- isdebug=$isdebug


log4j-executor.properties:
--------------------------

# Set everything to be logged to the console
# log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
# log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
# log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c: %m%n

# logging to rolling_file, using RolligFileAppender
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling_file

log4j.appender.rolling_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling_file.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/versa-ss-executor.log
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rolling_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling_file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN

# Allow INFO logging from Spark Env for EFM
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=INFO

# Spark 3.x
log4j.logger.org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=WARN

# Spark 2.x
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=WARN

# Reduce verbosity for other spammy core classes
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN


log4j-driver.properties:
-------------------------

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling_file

log4j.appender.rolling_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling_file.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/versa-ss-driver.log
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rolling_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling_file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c: %m%n



# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN

# Allow INFO logging from Spark Env for EFM
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=INFO

# Spark 3.x
log4j.logger.org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=WARN

# Spark 2.x
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler=WARN

# Reduce verbosity for other spammy core classes
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.ExecutorAllocationManager=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN
```

any ideas on what needs to be done for this ?

Question on -> ${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}
What location does this get translated to ?

when i logon worker node and check this, i get the following :

```
karanalang@versa-structured-stream-v1-w-0:~$ echo $spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir
.yarn.app.container.log.dir


In yarn-site.xml:

Here are the relevant configs:

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir</value>
    <description>
      Directories on the local machine in which to application temp files.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>gs://dataproc-temp-us-east1-939354532596-4ln8c3y1/fe57047f-13d9-4b9b-8bce-baa4a911aa65/yarn-logs</value>
    <description>
      The remote path, on the default FS, to store logs.
    </description>
  </property>  
 

However the logs are in the location below:

root@versa-structured-stream-v1-w-0:/# find . -name versa-ss-executor.log
./var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1664926662510_0002/container_1664926662510_0002_01_000001/versa-ss-executor.log
./var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1664926662510_0003/container_1664926662510_0003_01_000179/versa-ss-executor.log
./var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1664926662510_0003/container_1664926662510_0003_01_000250/versa-ss-executor.log
./var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1664926662510_0003/container_1664926662510_0003_01_000299/versa-ss-executor.log
```

where is the location - ./var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs - taken from (it is not in yarn-site.sml)?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

You can use a custom log4j config with RollingFileAppender to limit the log size for long-running jobs.

**Long answer:**

The default log4j config for Spark on Dataproc is at `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`. It configures root logger to stderr at INFO level. But at runtime driver logs (in client mode) will be directed by the Dataproc agent to GCS and streamed back to the client, and executor logs (and driver logs in cluster mode) will be redirected by YARN to the `stderr` file in the container's YARN log dir. Consider using `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties` as the template for your custom config.

In your custom config, you can configure logs to be written to a RollingFileAppender, e.g.,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling_file

log4j.appender.rolling_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling_file.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/my_app.log
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rolling_file.MaxBackupIndex=10
...
```

Note that for executors (and drivers in cluster mode), the value of `log4j.appender.rolling_file.File` needs to be a path under `${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66936895/log4j-filerotation-doesnt-work-in-spark-yarn) and this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application).

Upload your log4j config(s) to a GCS bucket, driver and executor may or may not share the same config. In your case, you might want to update executor log4j config only, just use the default for driver.

Then submit the job with the custom log4j config with one of the following ways:

1. The file name must be `log4j.properties`, driver and executor will share the same config:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark ... \
  --files gs://my-bucket/log4j.properties
```

2. The file name doesn't have to be `log4j.properties`, driver and executor can have different config:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark ... \
  --files gs://my-bucket/my-log4j.properties \
  --properties 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:my-log4j.properties'
```

The expectation is that there will be rolling logs under the YARN container log dirs (configurable through [`yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)  with default value `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs` on Dataproc) for the Spark executors, they will be automatically aggregated and stored in GCS and Cloud Logging.

Comment: thnx for the detailed note, i'll check and get back shortly

Comment: i've made the suggested changes, however - I still see logs flowing to stderr (though the new log file is also created), i've updated the details in the description

Comment: You mean the same log appeared in both stderr and the new log file? I don't expect stderr to disappear, but I expect only some YARN logs, not Spark logs, based on your log4j config.

Comment: another question on the ${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir} - updated in the description

Comment: no, the same logs don't get into stderr and rolling_file, i had a brief look and it seems the debug in the following code -> tdict = ll.map(convertToDict) - is being  written to stderr.. convertToDict() - converts the rdd to a hashmap

Comment: also, print statements in pyspark udf are still being re-directed to stderr

Comment: The user log dir is configurable through `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` with default value `${yarn.log.dir}/userlogs` see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: I did some search but didn't find a way to configure stderr. Maybe you have to consider redirecting it from within your application.